# add_rosteritem not working with xml_rpc in ejabberd server

Tags: mysql, erlang, ejabberd

I have configure ejabberd server 2.1.10 with mysql database integration,mod_admin_extra module and mod_xmlrpc module.

Issues is ejaberd admin commands like add_rosteritem, delete_rosteritem are notworking with xml_rpc.
When we use direct command line like,

***root@ejabberdserver:~# ejabberdctl add_rosteritem admin domain.com karthik domain.com karthik none both***

it will work and store in to database.

but same command does not work with xml_rpc.
xml_rpc does not return any error,   it retun ***{ok,{response,[0]}}***
But it does't store database.

Any permission issue?

Any body please help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I meet the similar issue recently, and turn out the root cause was there a bug in (svn)ejabberd_module source code, and this was reported in https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/issues/22 and fixed in ejabberd-contrib,

So I suggest you download the source https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib and rebuild the mod_admin_extra.